# Android app crashes without error log after experimenting with build types and flavor

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

Today i tried to play around with gradle build types and flavor. This is my build.gradle :

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("path to my keystore")
            storePassword "keystore pass"
            keyAlias "keystore alias"
            keyPassword "keyPassword"
        }
    }
    {...}

    flavorDimensions "tierList", "apiSdk"
     productFlavors {
         gratis {
             dimension "tierList"
             applicationIdSuffix ".gratis"
             versionNameSuffix "--gratis"
             signingConfig signingConfigs.release
             minSdk 24
             targetSdk 33
         }
         bayar {
             dimension "tierList"
             applicationIdSuffix ".bayar"
             versionNameSuffix "--bayar"
         }
         minApi24 {
             dimension "apiSdk"
             minSdkVersion 24
             versionNameSuffix "-minApi24"
             targetSdk 33
             signingConfig signingConfigs.release
         }
     }

     buildTypes {
         release {
             minifyEnabled true
             shrinkResources true
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
             applicationIdSuffix ".releaseVersion"
             signingConfig signingConfigs.release
         }
         beta {
             minifyEnabled false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
             applicationIdSuffix ".betaVersion"
         }
     }
     {...}
}
```

proguard-rules.pro

```
-dontwarn com.example.webtoon_gacha_remake_compose.Hilt_WebtoonGachaApplication**
-dontwarn com.example.webtoon_gacha_remake_compose.Hilt_MainActivity**
```

My app crashes immediately during splash screen without any error logs. I tried on my phone also in the emulator using all the combination of build types and flavor (6 in total).

My app also generate an APK with just 800 KB size, before was 9 MB.
[image]